# Yii2 save array of form fields to a single database field

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

How can I save an array of fields in Yii2 the current/default setup only works for field which aren't array.

Below are the form fields I need to save into the single field:

```
<div class="repeat">
<table class="wrapper" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td width="10%" colspan="4"><span class="add">Add</span></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="container">
    <tr class="template row">
        <td width="10%"><span class="move">Move</span></td>

        <td width="10%">An Input Field</td>

        <td width="70%">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'field1ofarray[{{row-count-placeholder}}]')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255])->label('Field Label') ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'fieldofarray[{{row-count-placeholder}}]')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255])->label('Som field') ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'field3ofarray[{{row-count-placeholder}}]')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255])->label('Field Label') ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'field4ofarray[{{row-count-placeholder}}]')->dropDownList(['instock' => 'Instock', 'soldout' => 'Sold Out', 'scheduled' => 'Scheduled']); ?>
        </td>

        <td width="10%"><span class="remove">Remove</span></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Current Controller (I need to know how I can loop through array and save as well as saving other normal fields in my form):

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new GrailWall();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my case I didn't need to make any changes to the controller at all.

You can just make a field in your db record, something like 'config_json` and then define a virtual property with getter and setter in your model.

```
public function getConfig()
{
    return json_decode($this->config_json);
}

public function setConfig($value)
{
    $this->config_json = json_encode($value);
}
```

Also set your virtual property to be safe in the rules so Massive Assignment works.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['company_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'], 'integer'],
        [['class'], 'required'],
        [['config_json'], 'string'],
        [['class'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['config'], 'safe']
    ];
}
```

Now you can set inputs like this in your view

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'config[ga_id]', ['labelOptions' => ['label' => 'Google Analytics Tracking ID']])->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use loadMultiple(), look at   [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html)

this is about tabular/multiple input.

Otherwise load the modal you need using  load($_POST[your_form_name].

Answer (score 1):

## models

```
public function getNetworkTypeArray()
{
    return explode(',', $this->network_type);
}

public function setNetworkTypeArray(array $value)
{
    $this->network_type = implode(',', $value);
}
```

## controller

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->setNetworkTypeArray($model->network_type);
        if ($model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
        }
    }

    $model->network_type = $model->getNetworkTypeArray();
    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$form->field($form, 'email[]')->textInput(['id' => 'email-0']);
```

will render:

```
<input type="text" name="Form[email][]" id="email-0">
```

Please note double square brackets in `($form, 'email[]')`.
ID attribute must be set explicitly unique, otherwise duplicate IDs will render, which does not conform with W3C/javascript standards.

Answer (score 0):

instead saving in array you can save in string, to that use tne variables as normal in the view, ex:
`fieldofarray` instead `fieldofarray[]`,

and in the controller use the implode function, ex:

```
  public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new someModel();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
          $model->fieldofarray = implode (",",$model->fieldofarray);
          $model->save();

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```