# How to save array of data to database

Tags: activerecord, yii2

How to save the bellow array of data to database using yii2 active record.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [UID] => RPS2019U002 [Name ] => Nishanth [Father] => mallesh [Mother] => Lakshmi [Occupation] => Govt Employee [Mobile] => 9856985689 [Email] => mallesh@gmail.com [Class] => UKG [dob] => 5/12/2016 [Route] => 1 [Addres] => Mysore [Remarks] => No ) [1] => Array ( [UID] => RPS2019U003 [Name ] => Nishanth [Father] => mallesh [Mother] => Lakshmi [Occupation] => Govt Employee [Mobile] => 9856985690 [Email] => mallesh@gmail.com [Class] => UKG [dob] => 5/13/2016 [Route] => 2 [Addres] => Mysore [Remarks] => No ) [2] => Array ( [UID] => RPS2019U004 [Name ] => Nishanth [Father] => mallesh [Mother] => Lakshmi [Occupation] => Govt Employee [Mobile] => 9856985691 [Email] => mallesh@gmail.com [Class] => UKG [dob] => 5/14/2016 [Route] => 3 [Addres] => Mysore [Remarks] => No ) ) [1] => Array ( ) [2] => Array ( ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use `json_encode / json_decode`.

You can also use `serialize / unserialize`.

**JSON** is far more portable. It can be used in any programming languages. (Wider format support)

You can create two methods with getter and setter:(Choose one of the above ways)

See this **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002068/yii2-save-array-of-form-fields-to-a-single-database-field)**.

For serialization:

```
serialize ([Array]); 
unserialize([Serialized value]);
```

**Models Rull**
If you want to check the array in Validation Rules:

```
['yourField',function ($attribute, $params) {
    if(!is_array($this->valueYourField)){
         $this->addError('yourField','yourField not array!');
     }
}]
```

**For example**, if your array should only be an integer. Use `allowArray`

```
['yourField', 'in', 'range' => [1, 2, 3], 'allowArray' => true, 'message' => '{attribute} is invalid.']
```

You can also check the contents of your array in your controller and After using the above methods, use `Safe` In the model file.(Rules)

```
 ['yourField', 'safe'],
```

**Note:** Do not use `implode()`. Causing a problem

Also check this [Extension](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/670/how-to-store-arraywidget-configuration-to-the-database-with-config-validation-rules) or [this](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-serialized-attributes)